# Help with Linux Install Dell Precision 7820 Tower

Tags: linux

I have a Dell Precision 7820 Tower with an Nvidia Quadro 4000. It runs fine with Windows. I wanted to install Linux on it to use it as a VirtualBox server. But when I boot Linux, I get the prompt to install and I select it, then it loads up and gets this error and the video is jacked. I can see that it is loading the proper screen, but the error and video are all jacked. I tried Ubuntu Server and LinuxMint, both did the same thing.

[image]

Comment: Have you try RHEL, ESXi?

Comment: No, but I did try Lubuntu and while I still see the error, Lubuntu's display worked fine and I was able to install it just fine, so I will just use it. It must be something on the motherboards pcie lane Linux doesn't like, but I don't know how to change kernals and stuff. I'll just use Lubuntu, it will only be a VirtualBox server so as long as that works I am good.

Comment: As I said try something different from Debian/Ubuntu derivate.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I notice same problem with NVIDIA T1000 by trying to install ubuntu bionic 18.04 LTS.

I don't know a solution yet...

According to 4.14 source code, https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.312/source/drivers/pci/hotplug/pciehp_hpc.c#L646
Power Fault over pciehp driver is an ISR handler check (bit tested is PCI_EXP_SLTSTA_PFD).

From this article, Operating Systems are certified to work on Dell Precision 7820 Tower:
https://ubuntu.com/certified/201702-25401
"This system was tested with 18.04 LTS, running the 4.15.0-1027-oem kernel.
This system was tested with 20.04 LTS, running the 5.10.0-1013-oem kernel."

I will try with an OS update version (Ubuntu 20.04). Some code have been added to manage emulated pcie bridge... It could be a solution.

Comment: This is useful information, looking at the kernel versions that have '-oem' names - Dell Ubuntu-certified machines often require bespoke kernels to work, and the generic Linux kernels may have issues. So it looks like the kernel that may work on this hardware is a bespoke kernel.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/442737)

Comment: Yes, I think It could be possible by using the DELL OS Recovery Tool which downloads the EOM Ubuntu (but only when an OEM Ubuntu is already installed). It could be tested...

Comment: Perhaps OEM version could be find here : http://dell.archive.canonical.com/dists/

Comment: usefull links : 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/926204/whats-the-difference-between-vanilla-ubuntu-and-the-dell-oem-version

https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/ISO-for-Ubuntu-14-04-and-16-04-for-Linux-based-Dell-laptops/m-p/4788659

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to disable some video drivers to [only use the system frame buffers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052289/cannot-start-ubuntu-18-04-on-a-dell-precision-tower-after-a-fresh-install-logi) (no display mode change). So add `nomodeset` into kernel command line from GRUB.

The kernel's command-line parameters, as per [The Linux Kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html):

> `nomodeset`
>
> Disable kernel modesetting. Most systems' firmware sets up a display mode and provides framebuffer memory for output. With `nomodeset`, **DRM and `fbdev` drivers will not load if they could possibly displace the pre-initialized output**. Only the system framebuffer will be available for use. The respective drivers will not perform display-mode changes or accelerated rendering.